# Enforce implementation of a globally accessible class in C#

Tags: c#

I need a globally accessible class in my project (like a static class). However, I'd like my code to force a user of my library to implement  it every time he/she uses it. Is there a way to achieve that in C#?

```
public static class Config
{
  // config details for the library 
}
```

The above code will be used across all library classes, but the details alter the way other classes respond. I would like a user to decide how to configure the library, that is write his or her own global Config class.

Comment: Force it by requiring an instance of the class to be passed to your library, do it through an interface.

Comment: What does it mean to "implement it every time he/she uses it"? Do they need a *new* class every time? What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen The problem is that static classes don't implement interfaces.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I want the class to be globally available from my project and I don't want to instantiate it every time it is used. At the same time I want to make a user configure its details.

Comment: If it is a static class, how the use of the library can implement it further? Can you explain your problem with some example code?

Comment: You mean you need a globally accessible *interface* reference?  Make it so.

Comment: The problem is that your library cannot refer to a static class, except by reflection, which, when good alternatives are present, is a very poor solution.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Can you give an example of a better alternative?

Comment: Yes, you provide an endpoint in your api which takes in an object implementing a specific interface, one you declare, this will force the programmer that uses your library to construct an object that implements the interface and provide that object *to* your library. This way your library doesn't have to go hunting for a static class.

Comment: Let's say I declare the static class you're requesting of me, how would you go about finding this class? Also, considering it is static, it cannot implement an interface, how do you know that it contains what you need the way you need it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want something like a generic singleton. Think of something like this:

```
public class Singleton<T> where T: ISomething, class, new()
{
    // not thread-safe, don't think it matters for this example
    private static Singleton<T> _instance = new T();
    public static Singleton<T> Instance => _instance;
}

public interface ISomething
{
    void DoSomething();
}
```

This way:

1. You have a unique instance of that class, accessed as `Singleton<Something>.Instance`
2. You force the client of the library to implement their own version of `ISomething` with whatever you want them to implement.

You can then use that class as a requirement on the classes you need:

```
public void INeedTheSingleton<T>(Singleton<T> instance) where T: ISomething, class, new()
{
    instance.DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: Why did you add "new()" keyword to the class signature? Is that mandatory in this case?

Comment: @aspdev It's mandatory for being able to create a new instance of that class. Otherwise you'd need a constructor that takes the object

Comment: Will Dependecy Injection work for your solution? I mean will I be able to inject a specific object where T is required?

Comment: @aspdev No, DI is basically the opposite of a Singleton. Your question is the opposite of a DI need